# Applying a distribution to data across time

Tags: r, dataframe, time, distribution, intervals

I have data on trains departing a train station every day over a month.
The data includes the departure time and the number of passengers travelling.

I have a separate dataset which estimates, in 5 minute intervals, the percentage of passengers that arrive over the 2 hours prior to departure.

Id like to apply the percentage distribution to each row of data, essentially generating 24 lines (1 for each 5 minute interval) for each train that departs.

Unsure of the method to achieve what I need, but the output I'm looking for should essentially tell you the time passengers arrive before their train departs.

Id appreciate any help with this.

Thank you.

| Train no. | Passengers | Departure |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11111 | 750 | 2018-01-01 07:00:00 |
| 11112 | 900 | 2018-01-01 08:00:00 |

| Hours before departure | Percentage arriving |
| --- | --- |
| 02:00:00. | 0.1%. |
| 01:55:00. | 0.5%. |
| 01:50:00 | 1.1%. |

Comment: Yes, this is quite possible, but it's not possible to give you any specific code without some sample data. Please edit your question to include a sample of your train data and passenger data (as text, not as images). You may find the `dput` function helpful for that purpose.

Comment: This is a statistical modeling question, not a programming one, so to me it looks off-topic for stackoverflow. It may also be more challenging than you think, because it looks like a non-homogeneous Poisson process may apply.

Comment: Thanks both - I've edited with a few lines of example data. Also happy to move this question to another community, could you advise where might be more suitable?

Comment: I'd suggest stats.stackexchange.com